# does not populate nested objects in breeze

Tags: javascript, json, metadata, breeze

I have nested json object returned from server, but when I use toType('Customer'), it doesn't not populate the nested objects. In the example below, Customer gets populated fine but not Orders and Items.

```js
let meta = {
 "structuralTypes": [
  {
   "shortName": "Customer",
   "namespace": "myApp",
   "autoGeneratedKeyType": "KeyGenerator",
   "defaultResourceName": "Customers",
   "dataProperties": [
    {
      "name": "id",
      "dataType": "Guid",
      "isNullable": false,
      "isPartOfKey": true
    },
    {
      "name": "name",
      "dataType": "String",
      "maxLength": 200
    }
   ],
   "navigationProperties": [
    {
      "name": "orders",
      "entityTypeName": "Order:#myApp",
      "isScalar": false,
      "associationName": "AN_Customer_Order"
    }
   ]
  }, 
  {
   "shortName": "Order",
   "namespace": "myApp",
   "autoGeneratedKeyType": "Identity",
   "defaultResourceName": "Orders",
   "dataProperties": [
    {
      "name": "id",
      "dataType": "Guid",
      "isNullable": false,
      "isPartOfKey": true
    },
    {
      "name": "description",
      "dataType": "String",
      "maxLength": 1000
    }
   ],
   "navigationProperties": [
    {
      "name": "OrderItem",
      "entityTypeName": "OrderItems:#dc",
      "isScalar": false,
      "associationName": "AN_Order_OrderItem"
    }
   ]
  }, 
  {
   "shortName": "OrderItem",
   "namespace": "myApp",
   "autoGeneratedKeyType": "Identity",
   "defaultResourceName": "OrderItems",
   "dataProperties": [
    {
      "name": "id",
      "dataType": "Guid",
      "isNullable": false,
      "isPartOfKey": true
    },
    {
      "name": "description",
      "dataType": "String",
      "maxLength": 200
    }
   ]
  }
 ],
 "resourceEntityTypeMap": {
  "Customers": "Customer:#myApp",
  "Orders": "Order:#myApp",
  "OrderItems": "OrderItem:#myApp"
 }
};

let config = {
 dataService: new breeze.DataService({
  serviceName: 'http://localhost/api',
  hasServerMetadata: false
 }),
 metadataStore: (new breeze.MetadataStore()).importMetadata(meta)
};

let em = new breeze.EntityManager(config);
let query = breeze.EntityQuery.from('Customer').toType('Customer');

em.executeQuery(query)
 .then(data => {
  //sucess - do something with data
 })
 .catch(error => {
  //error
 });
```

JSON data that sent by server looks like this:

```js
{
 id: "5091bed7-e035-45c6-b2c5-d1301e4170e6",
 name: "John Doe",
 orders: [
  {
   id: "5091bed7-e035-45c6-b2c5-d1301e419999",
   description: "food",
   orderItems: [
    {
     id: "82cbc916-c5af-4117-b759-830fe22e889f",
     description: "chocolate"
    }
    //more orderItems...
   ]
  }
  //more orders...
 ]
}
```

So I know data is coming back from server, and it populates customer object except orders and orderItems when toType('Customer') is used. I don't see any error gets thrown either. If I remove toType('Customer'), I can see data.results[0].orders are populated. Could someone please tell me why orders is not populated?

**UPDATE**

So I added custom JsonResultsAdapter, but it's still not working. When I debug it looks like it's going in right "if" statement in jsonResultAdapter, but data.results[0].orders always return empty array even if server returns data. I can see Customer is populated and typed, but not Order and OrderItems. What am I doing wrong?

```js
let meta = {
     "structuralTypes": [
      {
       "shortName": "Customer",
       "namespace": "myApp",
       "autoGeneratedKeyType": "KeyGenerator",
       "defaultResourceName": "Customers",
       "dataProperties": [
        {
          "name": "id",
          "dataType": "Guid",
          "isNullable": false,
          "isPartOfKey": true
        },
        {
          "name": "name",
          "dataType": "String",
          "maxLength": 200
        }
       ],
       "navigationProperties": [
        {
          "name": "orders",
          "entityTypeName": "Order:#myApp",
          "isScalar": false,
          "associationName": "AN_Customer_Order"
        }
       ]
      }, 
      {
       "shortName": "Order",
       "namespace": "myApp",
       "autoGeneratedKeyType": "Identity",
       "defaultResourceName": "Orders",
       "dataProperties": [
        {
          "name": "id",
          "dataType": "Guid",
          "isNullable": false,
          "isPartOfKey": true
        },
        {
          "name": "description",
          "dataType": "String",
          "maxLength": 1000
        }
       ],
       "navigationProperties": [
        {
          "name": "OrderItem",
          "entityTypeName": "OrderItems:#dc",
          "isScalar": false,
          "associationName": "AN_Order_OrderItem"
        }
       ]
      }, 
      {
       "shortName": "OrderItem",
       "namespace": "myApp",
       "autoGeneratedKeyType": "Identity",
       "defaultResourceName": "OrderItems",
       "dataProperties": [
        {
          "name": "id",
          "dataType": "Guid",
          "isNullable": false,
          "isPartOfKey": true
        },
        {
          "name": "description",
          "dataType": "String",
          "maxLength": 200
        }
       ]
      }
     ],
     "resourceEntityTypeMap": {
      "Customers": "Customer:#myApp",
      "Orders": "Order:#myApp",
      "OrderItems": "OrderItem:#myApp"
     }
    };
    
    let adapter = new breeze.JsonResultsAdapter({
          name: "myApp",

          extractResults: data => {
            var results = data.results;
            if (!results) throw new Error("Unable to resolve 'results' property");
            return results;
          },

          visitNode: (node, parseContext, nodeContext) => {

            if (node.id && node.orders) {
              return { entityType: "Customer" };
            }
            else if (node.id && node.orderItems) {
              return { entityType: "Order" };
            }
            else{
              return { entityType: "OrderItem" };
            }
          }

        });

    let config = {
     dataService: new breeze.DataService({
      serviceName: 'http://localhost/api',
            jsonResultsAdapter: adapter,
      hasServerMetadata: false
     }),
     metadataStore: (new breeze.MetadataStore()).importMetadata(meta)
    };

    let em = new breeze.EntityManager(config);
    let query = breeze.EntityQuery.from('Customer'); //removed totType('Customer')

    em.executeQuery(query)
     .then(data => {
      //sucess - do something with data
     })
     .catch(error => {
      //error
     });
```

Comment: Customer <-> Order should be a two-way association, with order.customerId providing the link from order to customer.  That way, when Breeze gets an Order, it will know which Customer to attach it to.

Comment: @SteveSchmitt, thank you. Could you show me how I do that? I am guessing that needs to be done in the metadata? JSON returned from server just puts orders without customerId in an array (as the example provided above), so I don't know how I can associate Customer and those Orders. the id in Order is id of Order not Customer. The same applies to OrderItems.

Comment: @SteveSchmitt, I added a custom JsonResultsAdapter, but it's still not working. Any idea, why?